# Pytest getting test Information in classes other than testcase

Tags: python, pytest, contextmanager

I am writing a test framework using pytest. Is there a way to get testcase object in classes other than testcase. For example utility classes.

I want to print the testcase name and some markers for the test in utility classes. Are these information available in some contextmanager?

Comment: When do you need this? There are a few hooks in pytest where you  can get test information during test collection, run and finalizing, but I'm not sure if that is what you want. What do you mean by utility classes? Can you show how this shall look?

Comment: For example: LoggerUtils.log() i want to print testcase name. This might be called in non testcasefile. Want to print which testcase called it and what markers does it currently have?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly access `pytest` test properties if you are not inside a test fixture or a hook function, as there is no fixed test case class as in `unittest`. Your best bet is probably to get this information in a fixture and store it globally for access from a utility function:

```
testinfo={} 

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def test_info(request):
    global testinfo
    testinfo['name'] = request.node.name
    testinfo['markers'] = [m.name for m in request.node.iter_markers()]
    ...
    yield  # the information is stored at test start... 
    testinfo = {}  # ... and removed on test teardown 

def utility_func():
    if testinfo:
        print(f"Name: {testinfo['name']} Markers: {testinfo['markers']}")
   ...
```

Or, the same if you use a test class:

```
class TestSomething:
    def setup_method(self):
        self.testinfo = {}

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def info(self, request):
        self.testinfo['name'] = request.node.name
        self.testinfo['markers'] = [m.name for m in
                                    request.node.iter_markers()]
        yield  # the information is stored at test start...
        self.testinfo = {}  # ... and removed on test teardown

    def utility_func(self):
        if self.testinfo:
            print(f"Name: {self.testinfo['name']} Markers:"
                  f" {self.testinfo['markers']}")

    @pytest.mark.test_marker
    def test_something(self):
        self.utility_func()
        assert True
```

This will show the output:

```
Name: test_something Markers: ['test_marker']
```

This will work if you call the utility function during test execution - otherwise no value will be set.

Note however that this will only work reliably if you execute the test synchronously. If using `pytest-xdist` or similar tools for asynchronous test execution, this may not work due to the `testinfo` variable being overwitten by another test (though that depends on the implementation - it may work, if the variables are copied during a test run). In that case you can to do the logging directly in the fixture or hook function (which may generally be a better idea, depending on your use case).

For more information about available test node properties you can check the documentation of a [request node](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#node).

Comment: Thanks MrBean for the detailed explanation. Is there a way i do this using contextmanager?

Comment: Not sure what you mean - what shall that contextmanager do, and where do you want to use it?

Comment: Every start of test we fill in the data in context manager and then use that context until the end of the testcase?. I havent used context manager much so dont know much about  it

Comment: Well, that's what fixtures are for - they basically work like a context manager. They are called on test start (the part up to and including the `yield`) and resume after test end (e.g. execute the code after `yield`, if any), as I tried to show in the comments.

Comment: yes right. but my utility might not be in testcase class

Comment: Well, you have to call your utility from a fixture in that case. As I wrote, the information is only available during the test, so you _have_ to do it in some test-related function.